# Devise Reset Authentication Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise and I have an authentication_token that I pass in the header of my API calls

How do I reset that token when the user logs out?

I want a new token generated every time they are logging in.

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly... Is it your authentication token to external service (like google) or is it a token how clients can log in to your app?

Comment: The token is passed in the header of my api calls

Comment: Are you using a gem for this token? has_secure_token? or something custom?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the **[after_database_authentication](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#after_database_authentication-instance_method)** callback on the model.

```
def after_database_authentication
  self.update_attribute(:auth_token, generated_token)
end

def generated_token
   ...
end
```